# TypeError: contract.test is not a function tronweb nodejs

Tags: node.js, http, tron, tronweb

I am trying to access Tron smart contract which is deployed on the Shasta test network using Tron-Web. I am using **node-casiko server** Following is my code:

```
const TronWeb = require('tronweb')

// This provider is optional, you can just use a url for the nodes instead
const HttpProvider = TronWeb.providers.HttpProvider;


const fullNode = 'https://api.shasta.trongrid.io';
const solidityNode = 'https://api.shasta.trongrid.io';
const eventServer = 'https://api.shasta.trongrid.io';
const privateKey = 'my test account private key';

const tronWeb = new TronWeb(
    fullNode,
    solidityNode,
    eventServer,
    privateKey
);


module.exports = {
        tmp: async function (req, res, next){
                try{
                        var contract = await tronWeb.trx.getContract("TS71i14jzLawbtu4qPDKEsFERSp6CQb93948");
                        //res.send(contract)
                        var result = await contract.test().call();
                        //res.send(result);
                }
                catch(err){
                        console.error(err)
                }
        }
}
```

When I execute this js file using **node** having **version v10.15.3**. I am getting Error as:

> TypeError: contract.test is not a function
>       at tmp (/home/administrator/node-Casiko/models/tronContract.js:25:32)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)

If I print the contract variable it is printing all information about the contract, but it is not calling the contract methods. Can somebody help me with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I managed to find an answer for self-question. Just change the code as below. It works!!

```
module.exports = {
        tmp: async function (req, res, next){
                try{
                        var contract = await tronWeb.contract()
                                   .at("TS71i14jzLawbtu4qPDKEsFERSp6CQb93948")
                        var result = await contract.test().call();
                }
                catch(err){
                        console.error(err)
                }
        }
```